# Shorten the regular expression into a single matching group

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Currently I am using the RegExp `(?:\(\) => (.*)|return (.*);)` for a custom `nameof` function that is called like this: `nameof(() => myVariable)`. Depending on the execution though the lambda is transpiled into something that contains the `return myVariable;` part therefore I need an alternative branch looking for `return`.

The transpiled output will be of the form `()=>{cov_26zslv4jy3.f[9]++;cov_26zslv4jy3.s[38]++;return options.type;}`.

Examples are the following:

```
// should return "foo"
() => foo
// should return "foo.bar"
() => foo.bar
// should return "options.type"
()=>{cov_26zslv4jy3.f[9]++;cov_26zslv4jy3.s[38]++;return options.type;}
```

My current RegExp works however it has two matching groups depending on the type of whether the lambda was transpiled or not. Is it possible to rewrite the expression such I have a single matching group which will contain the name?

---

For further details, I have attached the full code of my function:

```js
const nameofValidator: RegExp = new RegExp(/(?:\(\) => (.*)|return (.*);)/);

/**
 * Used to obtain the simple (unqualified) string name of a variable.
 * @param lambda A lambda expression of the form `() => variable` which should be resolved.
 */
export function nameof<TAny>(lambda: () => TAny): string {
    const stringifiedLambda: string = String(lambda);
    const matches: RegExpExecArray | null = nameofValidator.exec(stringifiedLambda);
    if (matches === null) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Lambda expression must be of the form `() => variable'.", nameof(() => lambda));
    }

    if (matches[1] !== undefined) {
        return matches[1];
    }
    if (matches[2] !== undefined) {
        return matches[2];
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Lambda expression must be of the form `() => variable'.", nameof(() => lambda));
}
```

Comment: @revo It was a mistake, I removed the tag. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Couldn't you use `(?:\(\) =>|return) ([^;]*)`?

Comment: @revo It seems to go in the right direction but it is currently matching multi-line even if specifically adding the `/s` option.

Comment: Try [`(?:\(\)\s*=>|return)\s*([^;]*(?:;.+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/UooHAT/1)

Comment: @revo You might have misread my transpiled output - I have added further examples with expected values.

Comment: How about [`\(\) *=>\S* ([^;\n]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/a7e95d/1) also with first regex you could have `\n` in negated character class `(?:\(\) =>|return) ([^;\n]*)`

Comment: @revo Ah it works now. I will stick to `(?:\(\) =>|return) ([^;\n]*)` which seems more robust since I can't say for sure which outputs other transpiler plugins will yield. That did it!

Comment: @revo Forgot to add that I'd gladly accept your answer if you post it as such instead of a comment :)

Comment: Glad that it worked but I'm not sure if spaces between `()` and `=>` are on purpose? If they are known first approach's good.

Comment: @revo In the first branch for the untranspiled the space is on purpose and enforced by my formatter and linter. So that one should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
(?:\(\) =>|.*return) ([^;\r\n]*)
```

If first side of alternation is not found engine tries the second. If we know one condition should satisfy engine at any time, greedy dot `.*` will make it to happen earlier. You may need `^` anchor too.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/e1ldOx/1)

There is a second approach too:

```
\(\) *=>.* ([^;\r\n]+)
```